# Call an MVC ActionResult with Quartz

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net, actionresult

I'm trying to set up quartz to stream values to the client using SSEs (server sent events). What I'd like to do is call an ActionResult in the controller every 5 seconds, which will send the updated value to the client. Currently I have Quartz set up to trigger the `Execute()` method of `MtGoxTickerJob`, a class derived from  `IJob`. I'm unable to call an ActionResult this way, because MtGoxTickerJob is outside of the controller's context (there seem to be ways of doing it, but all ugly workarounds). Is there a way to set up an MVC ActionResult as the job triggered by a Quartz scheduler?

```
 //Quartz Scheduler

        // construct a scheduler factory
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        // get a scheduler
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();


        IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<MtGoxTickerJob>()
        .WithIdentity("TestJob")
        .Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .ForJob(jobDetail)
            .WithCronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")
            .WithIdentity("TestTrigger")
            .StartNow()
            .Build();
        sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        sched.Start();
```

Comment: I don't think you will be able to acheive what you need here. This is not how HTTP protocol works (request -> response). Have you considered SignalR http://signalr.net/? Sample: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr

Comment: I've looked into signalR - but server sent events are supposedly more efficient? http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2012/04/10/using-html5-server-sent-events-with-json-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Not sure what is more efficient - I think it need to be tried. As for using approach you mentioned: as far as I see there is no need to access to MVC stuff at all. You should put your events into static BlockingCollection (in Quartz job for example) and then have action which will be pinged by javascript to get events list (or last event).

Answer (score 0):

How about making a call to the action using a regular http client? In the end, if it's returning an actionresult then you should probably make an http call to it.